# Cannot import a method from sklearn (using VSCode)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-packaging

I'm using VSCode, and I import `KDTree` like this

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KDTree
```

while the KDTree stays in white(which means VSCode cannot find this method)

I'm using python3.8 on my Linux and 3.9 on my Mac

**addtional info**:
I've installed sklearn, and I checked **init**.py file in sklearn.neighbors

It looks like this
[sklearn.neighbors **init**.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUBCD.png)

Why the KDTree parts stays in white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `KDTree` is not highlighted in the expected color, it doesn't mean VS-Code could not find this method. It could just mean that you have not accessed this method yet in your program. Try creating a `KDTree` object, it should work as expected.

Note that if you haven't installed "sklearn" yet, you would need to install it first before using `sklearn.KDTree`.

Comment: Thx, I've checked. The problem is I even cannot go to the definition of KDTree(sad

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "cannot go to the definition of KDTree"? Also, I noticed the way you imported KDTree in the attached screenshot is different from what you have mentioned in your answer. Which library are you using?